# Can't generate a WS Client from a WSDL with CXF

Tags: jakarta-ee, wsdl, cxf, webclient, apache-axis

I want to generate a web service client from a WSDL, I tried with Axis2 and it generated the requests and responses java files but not the stub so I thought of using CXF to have a better result, unfortunately it is incapable of generating any file and there is no error message, I had an empty src directory.
Can't you help me solve this issue please.

Comment: Supposing to go with CXF, could you provide us some details about the procedure you followed and didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from your use of Axis 2/CXF that you're trying to generate a JAX-WS client.

If so, you don't need Axis2 or CXF to generate a JAX-WS client.

Every JDK since early Java 6 has shipped with the [wsimport](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) tool, which generates all the artifacts that you need to call a web service using JAX-WS.

Comment: Actually, I don't know the difference between JAX-WS and Axis2 Client ! what I have is a WSDL file based on Axis2 and I have to create an application that invoke the services included in this WSDL

Comment: What happens if run `wsimport your.wsdl`?

Comment: it generates some Java files ! actually I find the solution using WSDL2Java, I didn't know that I should specify the port type for every web service in the client generation

Comment: I think you will find `wsimport` is way easier. There's lots of JAX-WS tutorials around.

Comment: thank you Steve, and what do you think of using Maven for client generation ?

Comment: I use maven every day for this purpose. Be sure to use the [jaxws-maven-plugin](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/) and not the deprecated one from codehaus.

Comment: Actually I have no idea how to use it, so can you please recommend me a tutorial to begun with